# How to configure CUPS to share printers via IPP - and what network interfaces it listens on?

Tags: ubuntu, printing, cups

I have Ubuntu Server with CUPS, and a printer added to that server via IPP.

I'd like to re-share this printer to other clients via ZeroTier.

In CUPS admin, I've enabled " Share printers connected to this system".

I then added the printer on a MacOS system, using the IP address of the Linux server and the printer queue name.

However, print jobs do not go through.

Is there something I need to do, to get CUPS print sharing to work on specific network interfaces?

I edited `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` to add a `Listen` directive for the ZeroTier IP address:

```
Port 631
Listen /run/cups/cups.sock
Listen 172.24.182.95:631
```

However, this didn't do anything - and from the port 631 - is this just for the CUPS control interface anyhow? (which actually worked via ZeroTier even without this line).

Is there some other config that controls how IPP works via CUP?

Comment: Are you running a host firewall?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be.

I can connect fine to port 631 via HTTP in my browser - e.g. http://172.24.182.95:631/printers/.

IPP printing uses UDP 631, right?

Comment: IPP uses both TCP and UDP port 631. Both of these must be open in any firewall.

Comment: There's no firewall on the Linux Ubuntu machine, nor on the MacOS clients.